# Category Blog Joomla not responsive

Tags: joomla, responsive-design

I made a responsive website in Joomla with a Category Blog as Homepage. I style the index with a component in which the Category Blog is located. Everything responds perfectly but when the website is displayed on a mobile, the Category Blog doesn't respond along. It stays a certain width. I made it so that all coloms of my website turn to 100% when on a mobile but the colom in which the Category Blog is, doesn't do that. Is there a way to solve this? I can't post the whole code here because I don't know where to begin in the first place...

Here is my website: www.ostameerbeke.be. I hope someone knows the answer (maybe get a module that imitates the Blog...) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your .content div

```
 @media(max-width:768px){
.content {   
    padding: 15px;  
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.component{
border-right:none;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that didn't work it seems... It even gets bigger when I apply that code... Maybe a problem with the compenent-class?